# Flex - Dispatching Remote Object Result Event

Tags: flex4, amfphp

I'm developing a flex application, that brings data from server using "RemoteObject" . I am using AMFPHP for server side remoting. The problem is when i call a specific method using AMFPHP's service browser , result data comes up in 9-10 seconds. But when i call the same method from my flex application , it takes 20-40 seconds !!!

the code which is sending a remote object request to my server is

```
remoteObject.destination = "decoyDestination";
                remoteObject.source = "PHP/manager1";
                remoteObject.endpoint = "http://insight2.ultralysis.com/0Amfphp/Amfphp/";

                remoteObject.addEventListener(FaultEvent.FAULT,handleFault);
                remoteObject.addEventListener(ResultEvent.RESULT,handleResult);
                var params:Object = new Object();
                params.action = "default";
                params.ValueVolume = 1;
                timer.start();
                remoteObject.init(params);
```

and my handle result function is

```
private function handleResult (event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                timer.stop();
                CursorManager.removeAllCursors();
                Alert.show("result found at: "+timer.currentCount/60+" seconds");
            }
```

The average timing is 30 seconds at least. As much as i know about remoting with amfphp it should work more and more faster. Am i missing something ?

*Note: using FB's built in Network Monitor i can see that a request is being sent. But the response time and elapsed time is always blank. Event after the response is received

Any kind of help will be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: How much data are you bringing back?  There is a cost associated with the serializing/deserializing data and pushing it through the wire.  But having a 2-4x slowdown makes me thing your setup is kind of wonky.

Answer (score 0):

A few things I would like you to try,

1. Having the network monitor turned on, will cause the performance hit - so, turn it off,
2. Service browser is obviously not running in debug mode, if you export release build your project and try to call these services, you should be able to see the response much quicker 9-10 seconds as you would expect, (running the app in debug mode always takes more time, looking at the response time,i'm thinking that you are getting a lot of data from the server which obviously takes time when in Debug mode)

Comment: hi zeus, thanks for the tips. I found out the main black sheep was the gZip. I was compressing all my output data. It seems having gZip off gives me surprising gain in my service's response time. and about debug mode, will it really cost me 9-10 seconds !!! sounds really expensive !!